# how activate action in struts2 using jquery file upload plugin

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, upload

I am working on a project only needs one file upload at a time. And I am using struts2 and jquery file upload plugin. I see many examples but I don't know how to activate struts2 action in jquery file upload function.

This is my jsp

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="/myapp/trading_upload.action" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <span class="panel-title">Upload</span>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> 
                                    <span>Select file</span>
                                    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files">
                                </span>
                        </div>          
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my js, basically it's just the jQuery File Upload example code

```
$(function() {
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/myapp/trading_upload.action',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context = $('<button/>').text('Upload')
                .appendTo(document.body)
                .click(function () {
                    data.context = $('<p/>').text('Uploading...').replaceAll($(this));
                    data.submit();
                });
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            consolo.log('complete');
            alert("complete");
            data.context.text('Upload finished.');
        }
    });
});
```

And this is my struts.xml

```
<action name="trading_upload" class="tradingAction" method="upload">
    <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
        <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
</action>
```

This is my tradingAction, it's just a print since I want to see it's activated

```
public String upload() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("upload");
        return SUCCESS;
}
```

Should I use url: '/myapp/trading_upload.action' to activate action? But after I select file nothing happen. No action is activated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I realized I need to implement struts2 upload first, then I can combine it with file upload plugin to activate the action. And it works